# Jquery overlay is not working in ie with https

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer

Hi I have developed web application in mvc4 and jquery. I have hosted in iis server. First i hosted over http and it is working fine. after login when user redirects to dashboard i put overlay. It was working fine over http in ie. With https also it works in chrome but not in ie. Whenecer i landed to dashboard i stuck with overlay as i shown in attached image. [image: overlay stuck]

May i know any idea why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the browser console? Is it showing any error?

Comment: Thanks. There are no errors.

Comment: May i know what may be the possible cause?

Comment: Did you check any other https sites on IE? Do they work properly?

Comment: Yes. I am thinking may be version of jquery i used for overlay is not supporting.